# How can http call details on CNI layer of Kubernetes can be fetch?

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I need to fetch http call details on CNI layer of Kubernetes. I am using calico plugin to manage network policies.

Comment: What kind of cluster would that be? For instance if it's AKS, there's pod if Azure CNI and that would give you valuable logs. Also, any or every call made will be available as logs in kube-proxy and coredns pods. If you can please be sure if you are looking for an API to do the work for you or just kubectl logs -l key=value where key and value selects the Deployment of coredns and kube proxy command.

Comment: if you are on GCP you can get logs using stackdriver logging and use some filters to get HTTP calls from CNI pod core-dns and kube-proxy.